# Run jar through php

Tags: java, php, jar

Im trying to run a jar file from php using `shell_exec(java -jar C:/myfile.jar)`.
Its not working and Im getting the following error in the apache error log.
"java is not recognized as an internal
or external command".
Its working from the windows command prompt very well.
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the `java.exe` executable isn't on the path.

Just include the fully-qualified path to it, with quoting where necessary if the directory contains spaces.

Comment: Thanks for response. But still no luck. When I gave full path for java.exe, there is no errors reported in apache error log but the jar file is not working.
And there is no problem with the working of shell_exec() beacuse when I tried shell_exec("notepad") its working fine.
Also no mistakes in the path I gave too. I tried the same path in the command prompt and its working.

Comment: @gareebnavas: "is not working" isn't *nearly* enough information to go on. You should perform more diagnostic tests (e.g. creating a jar file which *just* writes to a file, or prints to stdout).

Comment: I tested with a jar file which writes into a text file. Still its working from command prompt not from php. What else should i check to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Again, "not from PHP" doesn't give enough information. What did you observe? Presumably the file not being written - could this be a permission problem? Does invoking something like `cmd /c echo > asd.txt` work? If you try to run a non-existent jar file, does that give a different behaviour? Are you able to capture stdout/stderr from the process - and if so, what's being logged?

Comment: cmd /c echo >
asd.txt is not working.
Im not getting any different behaviour for a non existent jar file and no errors are reported.

Comment: @gareebnavas: I think you should work out how to see any stdout/stderr output, otherwise you're basically going to have a hard time of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
exec("java -jar WaveAppender.jar ")
```

Comment: exec() is also behaving similar to shell_exec().